# Spring Security oauth2, why does my auth/token authenticates CLIENT but returns 404?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

**EDIT**

I've removed the incorrect configuration which I had posted here because I feel there is already enough incorrect/incomplete configurations out there. After a couple of days struggling It got everything working the way I wanted to so I posted it here as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a few days of struggling I ended up with a working configuration. Since there is a shortage of good working example on the internet, I will share mine here

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans         
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd">

<!-- <sec:debug /> -->

<!-- Used by the token store -->
<bean id="mysqlDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>


<!-- Server configuration -->
<oauth:authorization-server
    client-details-service-ref="clientDetailsService" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
    user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
    <oauth:authorization-code />
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials />
    <oauth:password />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<bean id="loggerListener"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.event.LoggerListener" />



<!-- Services for clients -->
<sec:authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</sec:authentication-manager>

<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetailsService">
    <oauth:client client-id="client1"
        authorized-grant-types="client_credentials,password,implicit"
        authorities="ROLE_WRITE" secret="secret" />
</oauth:client-details-service>

<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetailsService" />
</bean>

<!-- service for resolving our users. -->
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService" />
</authentication-manager>
<bean id="userService" class="our.UserServiceImpl" />




<!-- Managing Tokens -->
<bean id="tokenServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetailsService" />
    <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="${security.token.validitySeconds:43200}" />
</bean>
<bean id="tokenStore"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.JdbcTokenStore">
    <constructor-arg ref="mysqlDataSource" />
</bean>


<!-- Token Approval Handler -->
<bean id="userApprovalHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler">
    <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices" />
</bean>

<!-- Resource server -->
<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
    resource-id="myRealm" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<http pattern="/oauth/token/**" create-session="stateless"
    authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<http pattern="/oauth/authorize/**" access-denied-page="/login.jsp?authorization_error=true"
    disable-url-rewriting="true" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/authorize/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <form-login authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?authentication_error=true"
        default-target-url="http://www.ourwebsite.com/" login-page="/login.jsp"
        login-processing-url="/login.do" />
    <http-basic />
    <anonymous />
</http>


<http pattern="/login**" access-denied-page="/login.jsp?authorization_error=true"
    disable-url-rewriting="true" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <form-login authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?authentication_error=true"
        default-target-url="http://www.outwebsite.com" login-page="/login.jsp"
        login-processing-url="/login.do" />
    <http-basic />
</http>



<http pattern="/**" create-session="stateless"
    entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_WRITE" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>



<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
</bean>


<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="myRealm" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />
```

My `web.xml` looks like this:

```xml
<web-app id="Recipe_REST_API" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Our REST API</display-name>

    <!-- Servlets -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- filters -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>



    <!-- listeners -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Can you please share the complete web-app. Would be really helpful.

Comment: sorry, closed source application can't do. Which parts are you stuck with?

Comment: Actually I got something working already :) Thanks for checking anyways. I was stuck with this Exception "A redirect is required to get the users approval" and realized that I should not handle that exception and let it get thrown from my code and then Spring will pick it up and take care of forwarding the user to the appropriate OAuth provider page. This forum post over [here](http://goo.gl/wDaW5) helped me.

Comment: do u have a corresponding oauth2 client simplistic setup?

Comment: Wow. Thank you.  Best reference in the sea of garbage documentation and crap-torials out there.

Comment: @Hendrik, you answer is really helpful. i want to store my token in data base and client detail in database, so how many table we need to create for oauth ?